# "Overall" missing in Production developer console Tests->Overall Code Coverage . How to bring it?

Tags: developer-console, code-coverage

**"Overall" missing in Production developer console Tests->Overall Code Coverage . How to bring it?**

When I try to evaluate the organization overall code coverage in production, I am seeing a difference in Developer Console Tests-Overall Code Coverage area. The section that is in sandbox dev console is displaying it but the production one does not. Any suggestions.

Please see the screen for the difference.

**"Overall" displaying in Sandbox Developer Console:**
[image]

**"Overall" missing in Production Developer Console:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was added in Summer '14. Your prod org is still on Spring '14.

My dev-edition org on Spring '14 also doesn't show the Overall score.
My Spring '14 sandbox also doesn't show it.

My Summer '14 sandboxes do show it.

Comment: I checked the Summer '14 release notes again and it is not mentioned there..

Comment: Maybe mark this as answered then, so others can easily find it back as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Overall coverage by clicking the link to estimate total org coverage on the Apex Classes page. I tend to Run All Tests first, to ensure that it is as accurate as possible, and then I click the link.

Comment: It'd be nice to have an actual as opposed to an estimate. ;)